# How is the number of days in Beta calculated?

Tags: support, area-51, beta-phase

I'm looking on [area51 at the stats for TheWorkplace.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30887/the-workplace).  It shows 310 days in Beta.

I've been a member of the site since it went into private Beta and my [membership shows only 188 days](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/83/karlson).

Something seems to be amiss here.

So How is the number of days in Beta actually calculated?

Comment: Sure you're not counting "days visited" or something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I see your membership as "10 months (2012-04-10 20:11:06)" and "Private Beta start 10 months (2012-04-10 19:00:00)", both of which match 310 days. So the calculation looks correct to me.

If there is an issue, it's the 188 days of membership you claim, but which I don't see when I look at your profile. Perhaps you're confusing the days you were online("visited" property on your profile) with the duration of your membership?